# Add class to div if another div has a class

Tags: javascript, html

The question is associated [with this page](https://denhaagpress.com/product/pet-bedrukken/).

As I have marked [in this image](https://prnt.sc/1r6yu0t), you need to click on one of the 3 images first and then click on **Text** to get to that section so that you can see the **Input Text** and **Font Family** section.

When I select any checkbox in the **Font Family** section, I have added a script so that so that it'll add a `class` selected to the `form-check` class.

Now, I want that, when the **Arial** Checkbox is checked, a class `Arial` will be added to the Input Text area. Similarly, **Verdana** is selected, then a class `Verdana` is added there.

I have added the below script but it is not working for me:

```
if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(2)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("verdana");
}
else if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(3)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("verdana");  
    
}
else if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(4)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("verdana");
}
else if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(5)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("verdana");
}
else if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(6)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("verdana");
}
else if (jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.font_family > .form-group > .form-check:nth-child(7)").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("arial");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("comic");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("georgia");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("impact");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").removeClass("trebuchet");
    jQuery(".ppom-field-wrapper.input_text > .form-group").addClass("verdana");
}
```

Can someone please point me what I am doing wrong?

Sorry for a long post.

Looking forward to a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: Note that you can add or remove multiple classes in one call by putting them in an array or space-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the user will only have one choice at any one time but checkboxes allow multiple choices, hence you have had to write a lot of JS to get rid of settings, but the items will remain checked.

So get rid of using checkboxes and instead use radio buttons in a group then only one can be selected at a time.

Please show your HTML then I can expand this answer with the relevant code to suit your setup.

Meanwhile here's an example of altering the font family in a textarea using radio buttons. You'll see that the JS is very much reduced. Also it doesn't use a class for the font family setting, though this could of course be done, as it is simple to set the style direct just for this demo, though you may want to use a class to give options for those systems that don't have the font family you are choosing.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#Text');
const inputEls = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputEls.forEach(function(inputEl) {
  inputEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    text.style.fontFamily = inputEl.value;
  })
});
```

```html
<textarea id="Text">abcd</textarea>

<form>
  <input type="radio" value="arial" name="font" checked><label>Ariel</label>
  <input type="radio" value="comic" name="font"><label>Comic</label>
  <input type="radio" value="georgia" name="font"><label>Georgia</label>
  <input type="radio" value="impact" name="font"><label>Impact</label>
  <input type="radio" value="trebuchet" name="font"><label>Trebuchet</label>
  <input type="radio" value="verdana" name="font"><label>Verdana</label>
</form>
```